# Vue show modal click using data from JSON

Tags: vue.js

I have JSON

```
"8":{
    "name": "Dog",
    "age": 2,
    "showModal": false
},
"9":{
    "name": "Cat",
    "age": 7,
    "showModal": false
},
```

Next I used v-for to show data:

```
<div v-for="(animal, index) in animals" :key="index">
    <div>{{ animal.name }}</div> // Dog
    <div>{{ animal.showModal }}</div> // false
    <div @click="showModal(animal.showModal)">Show modal</div>

    <div v-show="animal.showModal">modal...</div>
</div>
```

Method function:

```
showModal(showModal){
    showModal = !showModal;
}
```

But function `showModal` not change value from `false` to `true`. How I can change this value to show modal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading from file you can try like this:

```
<div v-for="(animal, index) in animals" :key="index">
    <div>{{ animal.name }}</div> // Dog
    <div>{{ animal.showModal }}</div> // false
    <div @click="showModal(index)">Show modal</div>

    <div v-if="isItemClicked(index)">modal...</div>
</div>
```

In your data initialize `indexes: []` and go and see if your index in that array.

```
methods: {
    showModal(index) {
        this.indexes.push(index);
    },
    isItemClicked(index) {
        let test = false;
        this.indexes.forEach(i => {
            if (i === index) {
               test = true;
               break;
            }
        })
        return test;
    }
}
```

If you need to change data in your json you will need other procedure.

I think it was helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Not help, still Not change value from `false` to `true`

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `true` or `false` like boolean not string? Wait you have indexes in your `animals` data? Are your name showing?

Comment: Are you loading data from json file?

Comment: @mere96 yes, I see `name` of animal and I see `false` in second `<div>`. Type `animal.showModal` is boolean.

Comment: Check answer now. You can pass index in new array and then check if index is in that array. I think its good idea for start.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `@clikc`. Should be `@click`.

Comment: Yes, I change this, but that was not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Tempalte:

`<div @click="showModal(animal)">Show modal</div>`.

Method:

```
showModal(animal) {
    animal.showModal = true;
}
```